# Should some questions be made Community Wiki and reframed as polls?

Tags: discussion

The question that has drawn my attention is this:

[What are your favorite sources for news about Machine Learning and Data Science?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/538/what-are-your-favorite-sources-for-news-about-machine-learning-and-data-science)

In the comments there are some objections about the possibility that this question is subjective and is going to cause fist fights. Is is also has seen some downvoting. But there is a certain use for the community in learning what are the most used news sources about data science.

There is a certain format of asking [questions as polls](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4510/how-should-one-ask-polling-questions) on Stack Exchange. The principle is that these questions should be made [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) by the authors or by the moderators (especially when the original poster does not have enough reputation to do so.) There is no reputation gain from Community Wiki questions and it doesn't cost reputation to downvote.

Should this principle be applied for this case and in the future?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the community should first decide if these questions can be managed without them becoming an unbounded and unvetted list of random recommendations — but the Community Wiki setting should ***not*** be used as a way to somehow make these question "okay" by depriving reputation for the answers.

Community Wiki is not a way to compensate for questions that would otherwise *not* be allowed on the site. If the question would not be allowed *without* the Community Wiki setting, it probably does not belong on the site.

[**The Future of Community Wiki**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/)